# Flagging a bountied question to be moved to another site

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty, migration

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267317/how-do-i-check-if-my-vps-participated-in-a-brute-force-or-denial-of-service-atta) on Stack Overflow, which clearly should be moved to Server Fault. I tried flagging the question as off-topic, but my flag was cancelled with the error "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed." ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv1CN.jpg)). It appears that the bounty on this question prevents me from flagging it, but it is obviously off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Is there any way to flag a bountied post as off-topic, or to recommend it be moved? I flagged it for moderator attention, but I feel this should be brought up, as it is a fairly obvious flaw in the bounty "protection" system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do exactly what you did - raise a custom flag on the question and explain the situation. That's what custom flags are for - getting moderators involved in those weird situations where *you can't fix the problem yourself*.

It's very intentional that bounties restrict a lot of your actions. Migrating a bounty with a question would just cause more oddities. The user may not have had enough reputation on the target site, or may not even have an account there yet. That's why you need to get a moderator involved - they can remove the bounty and then migrate it to the appropriate place (assuming they deem it should be migrated in the first place).