# Why was my flag for this 'code-review'-like question as being opinion-based declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, declined-flags

I was browsing the bountied section of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371560/how-to-efficiently-process-a-list-that-continously-being-appended-with-new-item) post which I thought was opinion-based.

Initially, the question asked for "any suggestion on how to improve the above code efficiency." I tried to flag it as opinion-based, but due to the bounty, I couldn't. It appears to be much more of a Code Review question than an SO question. As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288903/flagging-a-bountied-question-to-be-moved-to-another-site), I flagged it for 'in need of moderator intervention'.

Before flagging, I found [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow) about optimizing code, in which there's a highly upvoted comment/answer:

> requests for 'optimize this for me' are not welcome on SO - they are overly open ended. If the OP has a specific optimization they would like to ask about, that's different.

My flag was declined for the following reason:

> It's not opinion-based. And while it might be suitable for Code Review, that in itself doesn't make it off-topic for SO, so it shouldn't be closed.

My question boils down to:

1. More clarification on this declined flag
2. What can I do in the future to better determine whether a post is off-topic?

Comment: Seems like you think it needs more focus, if so then perhaps that's what you should flag.

Comment: I agree that the question is not well scoped – "How can I speed up the running time?" can be answered from anything of fixing a few lines to completely rewriting the thing. I would probably have voted as needing *details or clarity* to constraint the question, but I see how you arrived at it being opinion based. Every answerers' favourite optimisation approach seems fair game.

Comment: Did you flag the initial version, which as far as I can tell only had "Request: Appreciate for any suggestion on how to improve the above code  efficiency." as the only concrete, well, request?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I flagged the original version. Not sure if "how can I speed up the running time?" is much better though. It's still an "optimize this for me"-type question

Comment: They're clearly seeking to reduce what is currently an exponential solution and may take days to run into something more manageable that can be executed in a reasonable amount of time. I highly doubt they have *specific* performance requirements, like "each cycle must run in no more than 1.3 seconds", but, if anything, that makes the question *more* answerable, not less. Pretending that optimization questions are too broad is a game that too many people play. Some of them are, of course, but the majority are not. Asking how to improve performance of *specific* code is perfectly fine. @mis

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough, I certainly can get behind that canceling a bounty isn't something to be done light-heartedly. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fact that a question might be on-topic for another site does not make it off-topic for the site where it was asked. Topicality is assessed only in terms of the site where the author chose to ask it. That question is not off-topic for Stack Overflow. We do not close or migrate questions unless they are off-topic. Aside from the red herring that is the existence of a "Code Review" site, that question wasn't asking for opinions, not even in the original form.

Comment: Hey Cody, thanks for your answer. I feel now as though I should have been more focused in my flag, in that I wasn't flagging it because it was a good fit for another site, but rather that I was of the opinion that the question needed a more specific/less open-ended purpose. I came to this conclusion because of the first quote in my post, which seems to align with what the question at hand is asking for.

Comment: It seems to me a specific optimization task they want help with (speed up running time, making it no longer exponential), and they present sufficient code to scope it to a point where it *seems* like it can be reasonably answered. While I have significant expertise in code optimization, I know little to nothing about Python, so perhaps it was unfair your flag happened to be reviewed by a mod without subject-matter expertise, but the bar for canceling a bounty and unilaterally closing a question is pretty high, and I just don't think that one rises anywhere close to being unsuitable for SO.

Comment: To be fair, the question seems to (still) lack a critically needed piece of information: how long/short of a runtime would be an acceptable improvement in terms of runtime? I've left a comment on the question for OP to provide that information. _Open-ended/unspecified_ code improvement questions _are_ close-worthy here, generally.

Comment: The way I interpret it, *any* improvement in terms of run-time compared to what they have would be acceptable, but *ideally*, they would like to be able to go from the current exponential time complexity to something less than that. When we say "open-ended/unspecified code improvement questions", we mean things like, "How can I make my code better?", not that users are unable to ask a question about improving the performance of their code without having specific running-time targets.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to flag it as opinion-based

It is not opinion-based. That would be something like "Is this code good, what do you guys think?" Another scenario would be asking about how to improve coding style - such a question would probably be closed as opinion-based on SO and it would probably be better received on Code Review.

There may be open-ended "improve performance" questions that could be off-topic when the OP has not made an attempt to benchmark and/or improve. These could be closed as too broad. Or in some cases unclear if it lacks details about how something was compiled/benchmarked.

---

> requests for 'optimize this for me' are not welcome on SO

That would be because all questions along the lines of "do my work for me" are not well-received. Good questions show research effort.

---

The question you linked would probably have been more suitable for Code Review indeed, but overall, Code Review and SO have overlapping scopes. Questions about how to improve complete, working code are generally best asked at Code Review, but that doesn't make them off-topic on SO.

To know where a question belongs, please check out [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I don't really see how "improve coding style" significantly differs from "improve code performance". There's a plethora of options, from cleaning up the code to changing its architecture down to swapping out the runtime or even adding a compiler. As far as I can tell, unless the question is sufficiently constrained people have to answer with their personal preference of what an appropriate optimisation is.

Comment: I think you can assume that the person wants to stick with the language they've written it in. Otherwise, suggestions about how to optimize the performance are fair-game. There are always multiple ways to solve any problem; this is not unique to performance questions.